# How do I play split screen in the Nintendo Switch Resident Evil 5 demo?

Tags: nintendo-switch, resident-evil-5

I've seen people playing local coop in split screen with Resident Evil 5. How do you do it in the Nintendo Switch demo?

Answer (score 2):

1. In the **Main Menu**, press **PLAY GAME**
2. Select **EPISODES**
3. Choose **NEW GAME** or CHAPTER SELECT *(choosing new game in this tutorial)*
4. Pick Difficulty
5. In the next screen that appears, navigate to the top option, **GAME TYPE**. The default mode should be SINGLE PLAYER
6. Change the Game Type to **SPLIT-SCREEN** *(last option, press Right twice)*
7. Press START GAME and enjoy local split-screen co-op :)

[image: Split-Screen game type in RE5 Switch]

*Image courtesy of [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAQKkSWr5X0) -- it's showing CO-OP, but you should press Right once more to select SPLIT-SCREEN. This is the best screenshot I could find*

Comment: If you happen to choose CO-OP, then once gameplay starts, press Start and select SPLIT-SCREEN in the menu to change. You'll be prompted to connect 2 controllers :)